# Execute wkhtmltopdf with a browser session from laravel

Tags: php, laravel, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to develop an app to convert html to pdf using wkhtmltopdf, but my web app uses a login in order to see the page I want to convert.

I need to execute throug php something like this:

wkhtmltopdf --cookie 'sessionid' '12345asdf' 127.0.0.1:8000

But I don't know how to add this session from laravel.

I'm doing just this. And it works but I get the an almost empty page, I get my "loading" page and that's why I think that the problem is that I don't have the session.

```
$output = shell_exec('wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com/ google.pdf');
```

Comment: Show us something what have you done so far?

Comment: Did you check the lib: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy?

Comment: I have just discovered snappy, I'm taking a look, and it looks good but I'm having some other problems with it, my project was developed for someone else using api and vuejs and to handle functions I don't know how to call the php function unless it is through the vuejs component, because even when i added to the web.php file when i go to the address i get redirected, so this is just one of my problems. I don't understand the code completly. This was the only way I found in a way I could ask someone a little help, otherwise I have no more chance than try and error.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to convert a page to pdf with css3 compatibilty

Comment: Are you encountering any problems with the same?

Comment: I think that wkhtmltopdf is not gonna help me. I need to convert a page in the exact same way that it looks and it seems that there are no libraries that will support css3. You always must to give a new structure to render the pdf. I have given the html in a string instead of in a link and I have gotten the same result that with dompdf